# What cause the same css font style being applied to 2 different html files appear differently?

Tags: html, css

I am using the same css file on two different HTML pages for the same thing, on home page the fonts are looking bold but on the other page for the same thing I see some font size variation.

This is how it appears in the browser.

[image]

There is a font-weight difference in the pages.

**CSS code**

```
.nav a {
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
color: #0083b7;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 800;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0083b7;
font-size: 13px;
```

I don't know why is this happening, please tell me how to correct it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only problem is that in the profile.css your custom font is not being loaded correctly for some reason. In fact, if you try to put the same font to both pages with chrome inspector you'll see that they're pretty much the same.

On profile.css what you are seeing is not Merriweather sans , but just sans-serif. Try to find out why .

Edit, here's why:
In your profile page you missed

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,800,800italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

in the HEAD.. (html) you have it on your first page. Put the font loading in your profile page and you're good to go.

Here's the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1LjH.png

Comment: Thanks a lot you have resolved my headache.This is really helpful for me.

Comment: @S_PRATAP If Andrew's answer has resolved your problem please accept it as the answer (the green tick).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some odd repeated code inside the body tag on the 'gym' page.

```
<body promptdialogcheckdone="1"><embed id="__IDM__" type="application/x-idm-downloader" width="1" height="1" style="visibility: hidden !important; display: block !important; width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; border-style: none !important; position: absolute !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important;">


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Dear Fitness</title>

<link href="images/css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="images/css(1)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="/test1/css/profile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="/test1/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="/test1/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!---Footer --->
    /* snipped for space */ 

<!---Footer --->

<div class="green_border"></div>
```

Comment: I could not understand.please describe it. where I have made the mistake?